# Properly centering multiple variable-width children inside a variable width container

Tags: html, css

I have copied a simplified version of [this code](http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) into a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/suf3rwfg/14/).

The code is for a tree diagram written with HTML and CSS. The jsFiddle above looks good.

However, after playing around I have discovered that the centering of the nodes relative to their parents only really works if the child is the same size or bigger than its parent.

I am still really new to css, but the primary issue seems to be the fact that *all* `<li>` elements are floated left.

Consider [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/x9cfxxqg/2/), where the child is much smaller than its parent. Because the parent `<li>` is floated left, the child `<li>` gets floated left as well.

How can I fix this?

Comment: @JayMoy That works as a direct answer to the title. However, when the child node is not an only child, this will not work. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/4jytw9hx/17/  I am editing the question title to reflect this caveat.

Comment: @JayMoy simply removing the class form elements with multiple children does not work if each child is small. For example, remove the class from the two children in the example I just provided and you will see it is off center.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think playing with `display` set to `table` and `inline-table` might help.
Setting `display:inline-table` to the ul elements and `display:table` to all anchor tags in combination with `margin: 0 auto` seems to work.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 display: inline-table;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 text-align:center;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    display: list-item;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Parent</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">+</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child that is big</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">+</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child that is even bigger</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">+</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Child that is big</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">+</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>      
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works with multiple children aswell

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
body {text-align: center;}
.tree {overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;}
```

#### Preview

```css
/*Now the CSS*/
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

body {text-align: center;}
.tree {overflow: hidden; display: inline-block;}

.tree ul {
 padding-top: 20px; position: relative;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
 float: left; text-align: center;
 list-style-type: none;
 position: relative;
 padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
 text-align:center;
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before, .tree li::after{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; right: 50%;
 border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 50%; height: 20px;
}
.tree li::after{
 right: auto; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}

/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/
.tree li:only-child::after, .tree li:only-child::before {
 display: none;
}

/*Remove space from the top of single children*/
.tree li:only-child{ padding-top: 0;}

/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/
.tree li:first-child::before, .tree li:last-child::after{
 border: 0 none;
}
/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/
.tree li:last-child::before{
 border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
 border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
.tree li:first-child::after{
 border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}

/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/
.tree ul ul::before{
 content: '';
 position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%;
 border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
 width: 0; height: 20px;
}

.tree li a{
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 padding: 5px 10px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
 font-size: 11px;
 display: inline-block;
 
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 
 transition: all 0.5s;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

/*Time for some hover effects*/
/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/
.tree li a:hover, .tree li a:hover+ul li a {
 background: #c8e4f8; color: #000; border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}
/*Connector styles on hover*/
.tree li a:hover+ul li::after, 
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul::before, 
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before{
 border-color:  #94a0b4;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
 <ul>
  <li>
   <a href="#">Parent</a>
   <ul>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul> 
    </li>
                   <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
                <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>
                <li>
     <a href="#">Child</a>
     <ul>
      <li>
       <a href="#">Grand Child</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </li>      
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

#### Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/4jytw9hx/

Comment: This does not solve the problem, when the parent node is wider than the child node, the same issue persists

Comment: The parent node has `inline-block` display.

Comment: Can you give an example, where it doesn't work, I can fix it. @LukeP

Comment: Keep your CSS and swap out the HTML for the HTML I provided in my *second* fiddle. You will see the issue then.